# Kartik Gridview Export to PDF not updating PDF Configuration settings

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, mpdf, kartik-v

I am seeing an issue with how the Kartik Gridview and Exporter works.
I can create and render the grid with no issue, can enable and disable the various export formats. But when I try to set PDf Config options the PDF is rendered the same. Cannot change size, orientation,title, subject,etc. I can confirm the export is seeing the options, but it seems those settings are not saving prior to generating the PDF or they are getting overridden.

I have seen this same question presented on git hub but there is not been a fix or anyone presenting a working around.

Here are the config options

```
 $pdfExportConfig = [
        'showHeader' => true,
        'showPageSummary' => true,
        'showFooter' => true,
        'showCaption' => true,
        'filename' => 'Item Configuration',
        'alertMsg' => 'The PDF export file will be generated for download.',
        'options' => ['title' => 'IMD','subject' => 'Item Configuration'],
        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
        'config' => [
            'mode' => 'c',
            'format' => 'LETTER-L',
            'orientation' => 'L', // set orientation to landscape
            'destination' => 'D',
            'methods' => [
              'SetHeader' => [
                    ['odd' => $pdfHeader, 'even' => '']
                ],
                'SetFooter' => [
                    ['odd' => $pdfFooter, 'even' => '']
                ],
            ],

        ],
    ];


Here is a snippet of the view

 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'toolbar' => [
            ExportMenu::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => $gridColumns,
                'filename' => 'Item Configuration Export',

                'fontAwesome' => true,
                'dropdownOptions' => [
                    'label' => 'Export',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary',
                ],
                'columnSelectorOptions' => [
                    'label' => 'Columns',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary'
                ],
                'columnSelectorMenuOptions' => ['class' => 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'],
                'showColumnSelector' => true,

                'exportConfig' => [
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => $pdfExportConfig,

                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_HTML => false, // Disable Excel export
                    ExportMenu::FORMAT_TEXT => false, // Disable CSV export
                ],
            ]),

            '{toggleData}',
        ],

        'bordered' => true,
        'striped' => true,
        'condensed' => true,
        'responsive' => true,
        'hover' => true,
        'showPageSummary' => false,
        'panel' => [
            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,

        ],

    ]);

    ?>
```